# Can't debug Android app, gets stuck before I can hit any breakpoints

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug

Trying to debug and it gets stuck here. Exception: Can't find resource for bundle android.icu.impl.ICUResourceBundleImpl$ResourceTable, key en_US

[image]

I am able to run the app fine on the emulator and physical device but when I try debugging it gets stuck here and doesn't reach my breakpoint. Was working fine and now this started happening all of the sudden.

I've tried Invalidate Caches/Restart, cleaning & rebuilding project, restarting my device and my PC, checking out a different branch, even did an Android Studio update and still getting this issue.

Comment: Can you post your code here please ?

Comment: What code specifically? I don't think this is a matter of code as the issue persists on different branches who never had the issue before.

Comment: It might be class path issue. Please try this article https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/solve-javautilmissingresourceexception:-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-comconfig,-locale-zhcn

Answer (score 2):

After 2 hours I realized the problem was that I had "Java Exception Breakpoints" and/or "Exception Breakpoints" checked on the Breakpoints settings. Unchecked them and everything is back to normal.

[image]